# Blocked a frame with origin "<mydomain>" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com"

Tags: facebook, security, iframe

First of all, I checked this post already: [Facebook: Unsafe JavaScript issue (document.domain values should be same)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892556/facebook-unsafe-javascript-issue-document-domain-values-should-be-same)

But that is about a page on Facebook. The error I'm getting in my Chrome console on a page on my own website is:

`Blocked a frame with origin "<mydomain>" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.  fckeditorcode_gecko.js:36`

To be sure, I logged out from Facebook, but still the error occurs.

line 36 in `fckeditorcode_gecko.js:36` starts with:

```
var FCKTools={};FCKTools.CreateBogusBR=function(A){var B=A.createElement('br');B.setAttribute('type','_moz');return B;};
```

How to fix this?

Comment: did u find a solution to this... i am getting the same error

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a conflict between FCKEditor library and a library of facebook you included in the page. Probably the Like Button, I had the same with +1 button of Google Plus with api.google.com.

Quick Fix: Remove one the 2 library

Your FCK Editor library seems old also, you can update it here:
http://ckeditor.com/

Another quick hack to fix it. But I'm not sure of the side effect:
open "fckeditorcode_gecko.js":
CTRL+F to search the string:

```
"if (A.document) A.document.parentWindow=A"
```

and replace it with

```
"return"
```

Best,

Answer (score 2):

You can't, due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

It appears you are trying to add a `<br>` tag to the document in the frame. The domain, protocol and port must match for you to achieve this, or [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) must be implemented by the requested resource in the frame.

Comment: The strange this is: this has always worked, but just now it stopped...did the major browser implement an update for this recently?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with `ckeditor` (image uploader).

Here is what I have in `htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yousite\.co\.il
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yousite.co.il/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Anyone trying to hit www will get redirected to the site without www.

However, my admin page does not use the same `htaccess` rules and when I try to send ajax request with file from `www.mysite/admin` to `mysite/admin` and this create this problem.

Adding `www` to the url admin page string made it all work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for the contribution. While it sounds like you were also running afoul of the same-origin policy, I don't think this really answers the question. Your solution doesn't seem to apply to this case, the OP can't modify Facebook's `.htaccess` file or make a simple change to the address that's loaded in the `Frame` that will fix the problem.